# Php Echo not working on header?

Tags: php, mysql

i have installed mysql phpadmin, and my connection is also running, i have tested this already with an If else statement. the problem is, i cant see the echo on my program.

```
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', "root","") or die ("couldnt connect to server");
mysql_select_db("shelldb",$connection) or die ("couldnt connect to database");

echo "<body style='font-family: verdana, sans-serif;'>
    <div style='width: 80%; padding:10px; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; background-color: #fff; color:#000;>
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>
</body>";
```

Comment: don't echo a whole branch of HTML like this.

Comment: how do i solve this?

Comment: Check your server error log to see if PHP is reporting a syntax error.

Comment: First thing, you don't close your second `style` tag with simple quotes. `<div style='width: 80% ...  color:#000;'>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have echo problem, May be the problem in any other place. But you need not to echo the whole branch of HTML. Just check out the syntax.

```
<?php 
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', "root","") or die ("couldnt connect to server");
mysql_select_db("shelldb",$connection) or die ("couldnt connect to database");
?>
<body style='font-family: verdana, sans-serif;'>
    <div style='width: 80%; padding:10px; border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; background-color: #fff; color:#000;>
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: hmm still my webpage is empty? i really dont know where did i get wrong on this. the html code should already work

Comment: did you get the message like `couldnt connect to server` or `couldnt connect to database`?

Comment: hey i noticed i didnt put a quotation on the end your answer. now its working, thanks Man :)

Comment: carry on, And have a nice journey.